# React material-ui@next Tooltip in TableHead Cell does not render next to element

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using React v15.6.2 (and also v16) and `material-ui@next` (currently `v1.0.0-beta.12`), whenever I use the `<Tooltip>` component inside a table header, the tooltip renders off in the top left corner of the page instead of next to the element wrapped with `<Tooltip>`. If I cut/paste the tooltip into the table body, or anywhere else in my code, it works as intended.

**EDIT: When I say 'the tooltip renders' I mean the element that displays when you hover over the wrapped element inside `<Tooltip>`. The `<HelpIcon />` in my example below displays fine next to the text of the `<TableCell>`**

Here's an example of what I'm working with:

```
<Table>
  <TableHead>
    <TableRow>
      <TableCell>
        <span>Column Name That Requires Help Tooltip</span>

        // this tooltip renders off in the top left corner of the screen
        <Tooltip id='help' title='Info About This Column'>
          <HelpIcon />
        </Tooltip>

      </TableCell>
    </TableRow>
  </TableHead>
  <TableBody>
    // Tooltip works as intended in any cell in the body
  </TableBody>
</Table>
```

The only way I was able to resolve this issue was by hacking around the CSS in a way that made my end result not look like a table anymore (i.e. removing `display: table-header-group` and such)

Another thought I had is that I could try to override the absolute positioning of the tooltip to force it next to the element that's spawning it, but I would like to know why only inside the `<TableHead>` does the library fail to compute the position in which it should render the tooltip on hover.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I opened an issue on GitHub and it was resolved in the latest release.

https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/8467